# Difference between Promise.failure and throwing exception?

Tags: scala, promise, future

Is there any difference between these two ways of completing a failed Future? If so, which way is considered to be more "correct"?

Calling Promise.failure:

```
def functionThatFinishesLater: Future[String] = {
    val myPromise = Promise[String]
    Future {
        // Do something that might fail
        if (failed) {
            myPromise.failure(new RuntimeException("message")) // complete with throwable
        } else {
            myPromise.success("yay!")
        }
    } (aDifferentExecutionContext)
    myPromise.future
}
```

Or just throwing an exception

```
def functionThatFinishesLater: Future[String] = {
    val myPromise = Promise[String]
    Future {
        // Do something that might fail
        if (failed) {
            throw new RuntimeException("message") // throw the exception
        } else {
            myPromise.success("yay!")
        }
    } (aDifferentExecutionContext)
    myPromise.future
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [**What is the Deferred Anti-Pattern and how do I avoid it?**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-deferred-anti-pattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum That's useful info, but this question is definitely not a duplicate :)

Comment: @acjay as you can see - I did not vote to actually close it as such, I just found it amusing that the deferred anti pattern happens regardless of the language or implementation used :)

Comment: It was definitely still helpful, seeing the antipattern in a different language helped drive the point home for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like you're mixing paradigms. A `Promise` is an imperative way of completing a `Future`, but a `Future` can also be made completed by wrapping the computation in a `Future` constructor. You're doing both, which is probably not what you want. The second statement in both code fragments is of type `Future[Promise[String]]`, and I'm almost certain you really want just `Future[String]`.

If you're using using the `Future.apply` constructor, you should just treat the value produced as the `Future`, rather than using it to resolve a separate `Promise` value:

```
val myFuture = Future {
    // Do some long operation that might fail
    if (failed) {
        throw new RuntimeException("message")
    } else {
        "yay!"
    }
}
```

The way to use the `Promise` is to create the `Promise`, give its `Future` to some other piece of code that cares, and then use `.success(...)` or `.failure(...)` to complete it after some long running operation. So to recap, the big difference is that `Future` has to wrap the whole computation, but you can pass a `Promise` around and complete it elsewhere if you need to.

Comment: Sorry I think I left out some important info from my snippets there. I'm putting these snippets in a function that should be returning a future, and I've updated my question to reflect that. Am I still using Promise/Future incorrectly? (Thanks so much for your help!)

Comment: Yes, just drop the `Promise` altogether and let the `Future` constructor be the last statement in the function. And then let "yay!" by itself be the last value in the `Future`. It should basically look just like my example, but without assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Got it. The only time I should be using a Promise is if I'm completing it elsewhere. As for the question, I should just be throwing the exception to be handled later by future.onFailure.